# Copying x rows from a word and stops when it hits another word

Tags: vba, excel

I need to copy an unknown number of rows after finding a specific word until the next word comes along.

This is the database:

```
Counterparty | 721 | 721 Healthcare | CCY | Invoice amount
----------------------------------------------------------

12/03/14     |    12/10/14  |      081673 |        USD |     1000

12/22/14     |    12/22/14 |      081954  |       USD   |   999

Counterparty | 722 | 722 Healthcare | CCY | Invoice Amount
----------------------------------------------------------

12/22/14     |    12/22/14 |      081954  |       USD   |   999
12/22/14     |    12/22/14 |      081954  |       USD   |   999
```

This goes on and the amount of rows vary every month. I am only required to find one of the company(represented by 721). And what i need is to copy from the heading : Counterparty, 721, 721 Healthcare, CCY, Invoice Amount. Followed by the data beneath it until it hits a different company. 
Basically copy from only 721 and all the information until it hit 722 and paste it onto a new worksheet.

Comment: The best way to get help here is to first try something. If you get stuck, do some research, make an attempt at fixing things yourself, and only then ask a specific question about your attempts, showing what you have tried. Questions asking for complete solutions without demonstrating research effort usually get downvoted and closed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I came up. I do not know if there is an easy way but it is still working. There might be some unnecessary items, so please check.

The idea is macro is searching the word "Counterparty" through the column and identifying a range accordingly to copy. Then it copies and pastes the range to a new sheet with a dynamic name. I hope it helps.

```
Dim SearchItem As String
Dim SearchResult As Range
Dim LastRowWS As Long
Dim SWS As Worksheet
Dim CopyRow As Long
Dim PasteSeq As Integer
Dim CopyStart As Long



Set SWS = Sheets("Search")
SearchItem = "*Counterparty*"
PasteSeq = 0
CopyStart = 1

LastRowWS = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 1 To LastRowWS
    With SWS.Range("A:A")
        'dynamic range to find next item
        Set SearchResult = .Find(What:=SearchItem, _
        After:=Range("A" & i), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not SearchResult Is Nothing Then
                PasteSeq = PasteSeq + 1 'For new sheetname
                On Error GoTo LastRow 'For the last part
                CopyRow = SearchResult.Offset(-1, 0).Row
                Rows(CopyStart & ":" & CopyRow).Copy
                Sheets.Add.Name = "PasteSheet" & PasteSeq
                Sheets("PasteSheet" & PasteSeq).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                Sheets("Search").Select
                CopyStart = SearchResult.Row
                i = CopyRow 'SearchResult.Row
        End If
    End With
Next

LastRow:
Rows(CopyRow + 1 & ":" & LastRowWS).Copy
Sheets.Add.Name = "PasteSheet" & PasteSeq
Sheets("PasteSheet" & PasteSeq).Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Sheets("Search").Select
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the response. I really appreciate it. I getting error 1004. Application-defined or object-defined error. How do i debug this error?

Comment: Okay so i managed to make it work. Sort of. Right now its copying unnecessary rows it copies from the very first line of the worksheet until the end of the required row. Really appreciate your time in helping me.

Comment: No problem mate. I would appriciate if you confirm the reply if it solved your problem ;)